# Как убрать одновременную авторизацию админа в админ панельку и на сайт(Django)

Tags: django, авторизация

Проблема в том что, когда я захожу от имени админа в админ панельку, авторизация происходит и на сайте которую я разрабатываю, а мне это не надо. Я хотел бы чтоб авторизация совершалось по отдельности на сайте(для пользователей) и на админ панельке(для админа).(DJANGO).Помогите пожалуйста с этим вопросом ???

Comment: Единственным решением для меня стало открывать второй браузер в инкогнито

Answer (score 0):

> Проблема в том что, когда я захожу от имени админа в админ панельку, авторизация происходит и на сайте которую я разрабатываю, а мне это не надо. Я хотел бы чтоб авторизация совершалось по отдельности на сайте(для пользователей) и на админ панельке(для админа).(DJANGO).Помогите пожалуйста с этим вопросом ???

1. Для того, чтобы пользователи не имели доступа к админ панели, вам необходимо регистрировать обычных пользователей, они имеют признак `user.is_staff = False`.
2. Если вы не хотите, чтобы ваш администратор одновременно логинился на сайте и в админке - открывайте окно администратора в окне инкогнито.
3. Если вас не устраивают 1 и 2 вариант пишите свою авторизацию и список ролей или переписывайте джанговскую.

Comment: 1 вариант у меня уже существует. А вот 2 вариант мне понравился. Пока что сойдет, до продакшена. Спасибо!

Comment: Знаете как отблагодарить автора сообщения выше?

Comment: А можно спросить, когда я проект закину на хостинг, с этим проблемы будут? Или также надо будет через инкогнито открывать?

Comment: всё будет работать точно также

Comment: получилось ли решить проблему?

Comment: К сожалению ,нет. до сих пор захожу через инкогнито